# Is this UML Sequence Diagram for Desktop assistance system correct?

Tags: client-server, uml, sequence-diagram

I want to make a client-server application to help users and control their computer within a LAN network.

I have already started to learn UML, my question is:

Are there any errors in my diagram? How can I draw a correct one?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the diagram is supposed to clarify the system design and visually **document** the key use case then in my opinion it is **good enough** to leave it as it is and move on to other tasks (the ultimate goal is probably development of the application that helps users)

---

From the [UML Sequence Diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html) perspective there are a few concepts that might deserve some attention if you want to make it more "*perfect*":

- From the coder's perspective at some point the events performed by `Admin` will be stuffed (buffered) in a queue and delivered to the `Customer`'s machine as delayed and [asynchronous](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#asynchronous-call). **asynchronous messages** are drawn with open arrow head. In your diagram all messages are [synchronous](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#synchronous-call) which is fine for sketching the rough idea but it won't be the case once you start coding
- the interaction part (with mouse and key events) will be typically more complex and **repeating**. You can use [loop combined fragment](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html#operator-loop) (or nested combination of other fragments) to show it. The [interaction (re)use](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#interaction-use) notation may be also useful.

  Sequence diagram alone does not provide very strong means to express complex event flow with many conditions. `Activity Diagrams` are much better at that and [UML Interaction Overview Diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/interaction-overview-diagrams.html) may be the easy way out if it turns out that the interaction would be too hard to depict using only `combined fragments`

---

BTW: there are already some free-to-use applications doing what your diagram depicts, like [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) or [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx). Some of the [remote desktop software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software) *may* include useful (inspiring) diagrams as part of their documentation